# python 'int' object to str implicitly errot

Tags: python

Can any one help me fix the problem with this python program it keeps giving me an error.

```
import os
import time
import random
from random import randint
import string
count = 0

number = 1
while (count < 50):
    print(number)
    os.mkdir(number)
    count = count + 1
    number = number + 1
    print(number)
print("done")
time.sleep(5)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What error does it give you? Post your traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\.idlerc\test.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.mkdir(number)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're giving an `int` argument to `mkdir`. You need to convert this `int` to `str` first:

```
os.mkdir(str(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.mkdir` takes a string, not an integer. Just do

```
os.mkdir( str(number) )
```

instead of

```
os.mkdir(number)
```

Note that the exception you get when you run your script should be explicit enough:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.mkdir()` requires a file path as the parameter.

```
>>> import os
>>> x = 100
>>> os.mkdir(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
>>> os.mkdir(str(x))
>>> os.path.exists(str(x))
True
>>> os.mkdir(str(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '100'
```